# Rendering order in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get rid of a visual issue I got.
I have a ng-repeat displaying some stuff and a footer on my page.
The ng-repeat taking some time to display, I see the footer n my page before anything else and that is disturbing.

How can I force the footer to display only when something else like an ng-repeat has finish rendering on the page ?

Comment: use ng-cloak on page body , and include header or footer whatever you don't want to show before data rendering

Comment: I thought of that, but the page is already a big project, I can't use that solution that would change too much. But eventually I think it'll come to that. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat is rendered with a list of value; that you propably get from a WebService.

- add a $rootScope.myBool that is false at app start.
- Update that valueto true within your $http call (or way to fill your ng-repeat array)
- once your array is completed add a ng-show="myBool" to your footer to
  prevent it from showing before your array is filled

Answer (score 0):

It always better to create one service which shows loader icon full width when any ajax call or data loading is happening.

this is very normal scenario with angularJs SPA, that the page look distorted or footer coming first at page level, so better create one service which will enable full screen loader on the page when ajax call loads the data or ng-repeat is in progress and as things are completed same service will disable the full screen loader

something like this: to make loader service true before calling ajax and make it false as call finishes in success or error.

https://iamlalit.tinytake.com/sf/MTY5MDY2NF81NjM1Njgw

```
loaderService.toggle(true);

$http({
    url: enumApp.url.apiUrl + Id,
    method: "GET"
})
.success(function (data) {
   loaderService.toggle(false);
})
.error(function (data, status) {
   loaderService.toggle(false);
})
```